# Causation in an agroecosystem?

Tags: multiple-regression, model, ecology

I'm working in an agroecosystem with one specific crop and am interested in understanding how certain treatments influence given ecosystem characteristics (such as soil organic carbon). Variables that are known to influence these characteristics (beyond the potential impact of treatments) include soil type and climate.

I'm considering using multiple regression, with the ultimate goal of being able to predict how the given treatments will influence ecosystem characteristics of interest. I want to predict, given certain variables (climate, soils, and treatment), how the ecosystem characteristic will respond for this plant.

I had also considered using structural equation modelling to elucidate underlying mechanisms, although I don't think this would be appropriate here.

Will multiple regression be appropriate in this case, or should I use SEM or something else?

Comment: I don't see anything here asking for a dataset. I think the question of whether multiple regression will help the OP achieve their goals should be considered on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you have one response and several predictors (treatment, soil type and climate), multiple regression is the way to go.
- If you have several responses that react independently to your predictors, you simply run several multiple regressions. Word of warning: running multiple regressions for many possible responses and then presenting only the nicer part of them would qualify as p-hacking though.
- An SEM would only make sense if you can make up some causal link between variables. Your predictors don't seem to qualify for that, so a possible causal link could only be between your responses. Whether this is the case I can't say based on your description.